# ng repeat variable number of table rows

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I know how to use `ng-repeat` to create a variable number of table cells, but how do you do this with table rows? I'm trying to create a jeopardy style game where the number of table rows should equal the number of questions in each column. Here's how my JSON is structured:

app.js

```
$scope.subjects = [
{topic:'politics',question:['How do we fix our bloated economy?'],answer:'We trim the Fiat'}
//more questions & topics
    ]
```

Questions should be added to the column, and they should be organized by topic. I can't get off the right foot; in the code below, I try to create number of table rows equal to the length of the question array, but it won't work.

view5.html

```
<table>
<tr ng-repeat='i in subjects[0].question'>
    <!-- <td ng-repeat='subject.question[i] in subjects'></td> should get question for the corresponding topic -->
</tr>

</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code. Also go to http://skillcram.com/AngularJS.htm for a working example.

```
enter code here


<table border>
   <caption>ng-repeat</caption>
   <tr ng-repeat="citiTemp in citiTemperatures">
      <td>{{ citiTemp.time }}</td>
      <td>{{ citiTemp.temp }}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
mainApp.controller('example2Controller', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.citiTemperatures =  [
        { time:"12:00",
            temp:"0"
        },
        { time:"02:00",
            temp:"05"
        },  
        { time:"04:00",
            temp:"10"
        },  
        { time:"06:00",
            temp:"15"
        },  
        { time:"08:00",
            temp:"20"
        }   

    ];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be using as below

```
<table ng-repeat='subject in subjects'>
    <tr>
        <td ng-repeat="question in subject.question track by $index">
          {{question}}
        </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

My sample json is

```
$scope.subjects = [{
    topic: 'politics',
    question: ['How do we fix our bloated economy?',
    'a?', 'How do we fix our bloated economy?'],
    answer: 'We trim the Fiat'
  }, {
    topic: 'politics',
    question: ['How do we fix our bloated economy?'],
    answer: 'We trim the Fiat'
  }, {
    topic: 'politics',
    question: ['How do we fix our bloated economy?'],
    answer: 'We trim the Fiat'
  }];
```

**[LIVE DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/4BqyIzx4W8Em6VY1qBX0?p=preview)**